# How can I databind to a string array?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I databind a string array (`string[]`) to a `dropdownlist`?

Does it implement `iEnumerable`?

Comment: Yes a string[] implements IEnumerable[<string>] - but I don't know if that means you can data-bind in ASP.NET; have you tried it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, and yes.  All arrays implement `IEnumerable<T>`, and as such are valid data-sources for data-binding.